# Why do different Exceptions occur?

Tags: java

I am using the below code. The first line is giving `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, and the second is giving `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I'm unable to figure out why.

```
int intValue =Integer.parseInt(null);
Double double1 = Double.parseDouble(null);
```

Comment: Honestly what do you expect the behavior to be? Really?

Comment: read the chapter on exceptions in Head First Java - http://www.amazon.in/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/8173666024?tag=googinhydr2765-21 .. they explain exceptions quite nicely.

Comment: Stop downvoting, this question don't deserve these many downvotes. It's a valid doubt that one parser throwing one exception and where as  the another is different. A valid reason might be there.

Comment: I agree with suresh. The underlying question is "why does this give two different exceptions?", not "why do I get these exceptions?".

Comment: Because one person (or team) did floating point math, and another person (or team) did integer math.

Comment: My original read of this question was "this is not clear". It might have been better to pretend we (the readers) are dumb and explain what *exactly* you are confused about, as well as adding what you would expect to happen.

Comment: Upvote for asking the question.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: I believe the downvotes to result from an unclear question, the question in itself isn't a bad one though. However people who don't immediatly recognize the underlying question will downvote and move on. At least by compensating it with upvotes the question won't get bombarded with downvotes and it will probably still yield an interesting answer.

Comment: @SlyRaskal Instead of arguing about why downvotes are valid, maybe it would be more helpful to suggest some improvements? I see nothing unclear in this question, honestly. Okay, the English is a little bad, but it's clear enough to read. The title is sufficiently descriptive, even. I read the question and immediately see that the OP is confused by an inconsistency.

Comment: @ajit - Please accept the answer if you get the solution

Comment: @ajit Is your problem solved?accept any of the below answer.It'll help others

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because thats how they are implemented,

```
int intValue =Integer.parseInt(null);
```

If we look the parseInt implementation, they are throwing `NumberFormatException` if the input string is `null`

[image]

And `Double double1 = Double.parseDouble(null);`

In `parseDouble(String s)` method there is  another method call i.e `FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue();`
 In `readJavaFormatString(s)` method is where exactly `NullPointerException` is thrown

[image]

`FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s)` method

[image]

Comment: It's also documented that way: [parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) and [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Now this is quite an answer :D

Comment: @jpmc26 +1 Easiest than checking implementation :)

Comment: Extrapolating, we can say "parseDouble delegates to a method that was probably programmed by somebody else".

Answer (score 0):

This is how both functions are implemented in respective classes.

**parseInt** method validate the parameter:

`if (s == null) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("null");
}`

**parseDecimal** method first calls trim on the input string parameter:

`in = in.trim(); // throws NullPointerException if null`